# how one can take the load off mysql db, on a drupal 7 site with millions of nodes (8m)

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

i have a site that has more than 8 million nodes. The mysql database is having serious performance issues, so i was looking at ways to just take the load off mysql db in some way.

The biggest performance issue i have is on the views. And the problem is that i need to have always the latest data, so no caching is an option. I am looking at a module like https://www.drupal.org/project/mongodb but used for content types that all have fields of entity reference (https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference: Provides a field type that can reference arbitrary entities)
Given that MySQL is optimized, what one can do with the least amount of messing with code?

Comment: Why do you not use elasticsearch or apache Solr indexation , and make front query with it ?

Comment: i have tried, with solr, but unfortunately i have issues with the fact that i use organic groups. So each logged in user, must see different results. I can index nodes, but somehow i cannot make it work with passing to it also the group id of the logged in user. If there is somewhere an article, a case study of someone who has made it, please let me know.

Comment: Ok i understand this point. So , you're using contrib views module ? maybe you need to optimise request and limit with beetween instruction on date to avoid load all each time

Comment: Please elaborate on "node", "entity", etc.  And provide a slow query, together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.